# Symfony2 send back login form on each AJAX request

Tags: ajax, symfony, authentication

I'm doing a back-office image upload form using Symfony 2.5.12 (yeah I know I'm a little out of date, but I will work on that soon :)). I want to upload the images via AJAX, but I get a 302 redirect to the login form on every AJAX request I send.

Here is the JS part on my stuff (it is simplified because for the moment I just want to do a successful AJAX call without 302 redirect to the login page, so I deleted the data related stuff) :

```
form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const url = form.getAttribute('action'); // '/admin/uploadImage'

    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
});
```

And here is my action in my controller, bound to /admin/uploadImage URL :

```
public function uploadAction() {
    return new JsonResponse(array('test' => 'hello world'));
}
```

Every /admin URL requires ROLE_ADMIN role, I defined it in security.yml :

```
security:
    #...
    access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

This way, it is normal that a login form shows when I want to access to this kind of URL. But when I trigger my AJAX call, I'm already logged in because I'm on /admin/gallery page.

Does anybody can figure out what is wrong with what I'm doing ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is the cookie being sent with AJAX request ?

Comment: There is nothing that refers to the cookie in the request headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I absolutely don't know why, but it seems the issue was related to `whatwg-fetch` fetch implementation. I replaced it with `axios` and the problem is gone.